# callofduty is showing error?

Tags: xbox360

[image: .EXE FILE MISSING]

I am trying to solve the problem with iw4mp_ceg.exe in modern warfare 2 multiplayer.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Is it a legal copy?

Comment: yes  it is a legal one